# Azure IOT HUB, changing MQTT version?

Tags: azure, cloud, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, wago

I have a question about IoT Hub.

I installed a new flux from Azure IoT Hub to a device using Wage. The communication protocol used is MQTT.
The default version is : 1.0
My problem is the id-device which is not been sent (null value).
I want to upgrade the MQTT to a higher version on IoT Hub, but I failed :(
Can any one help me to find the easiest way to configure that ?
Is it just a configuration in the device twins ? If yes, whiche one ?

Thanks in advance for your help
Best regards,
Abdelrahman ELGAMAL
+33612946655

Comment: have a look at the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss . Actually I recieve the first message from the Wago Device called "Device Hello" with all supported versions of MQTT